# Using Javascript arrays to put random words into a madlib

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I am putting together a madlib site for a class and one of the parts of the assignment is to make a button that will randomly assign words from arrays into the madlib. I can't figure out how to get that to work. I've tried a few different things, such as:

```
let nounArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
function randomWord()
{
    console.log(nounArray[(Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length))]);
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work the way I need it to. It keeps returning all of the items in the array, not just picking one. The little story looks like this:

```
let storyContent = "All of the " + nounArray + " and " + noun2Array + " were gone when he awoke, finding that the " + noun3Array + " now continued uninterrupted in their place. He tried to " + verbArray + " for help, but was " + adjectiveArray + " to find that his mouth was " + adjective2Array + ", the lower half of his face now " + adjective3Array + ", continuous flesh. He tried to " + verb2Array + " his panic by closing his eyes and counting to ten. On the eleventh second of darkness, he realised his mistake."
```

inside my madlib2() function.

Do I need to do something different with the nounArray, noun2Array, etc., within the storyContent? The main part of the assignment works (the part where you request that a person inputs different words and they are inserted into the story), this is the only part I can't get to work. Any ideas? I'll include the full Javascript below just in case.

```
var noun = [];
var noun2 = [];
var noun3 = [];
var verb = []
var verb2 = []
var adjective = [];
var adjective2 = [];
var adjective3 = [];
var storyContent = ""; //story that will be displayed when run

madlib(); //madlib function

function madlib()
{
    let wordform = document.getElementById("wordform"); //calls the form in the HTML
    let noun = document.getElementById("Noun").value;
    let noun2 = document.getElementById("Noun2").value;
    let noun3 = document.getElementById("Noun3").value;
    let verb = document.getElementById("Verb").value;
    let verb2 = document.getElementById("Verb2").value;
    let adjective = document.getElementById("Adjective").value;
    let adjective2 = document.getElementById("Adjective2").value;
    let adjective3 = document.getElementById("Adjective3").value;

    let storyContent = "All of the " + noun + " and " + noun2 + " were gone when he awoke, finding that the " + noun3 + " now continued uninterrupted in their place. He tried to " + verb + " for help, but was " + adjective + " to find that his mouth was " + adjective2 + ", the lower half of his face now " + adjective3 + ", continuous flesh. He tried to " + verb2 + " his panic by closing his eyes and counting to ten. On the eleventh second of darkness, he realised his mistake."

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = storyContent;
}

let generateBtn = document.getElementById("button");
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', madlib);

const nounArray = ["pebbles", "shoes", "trees"];
let noun2Array = ["seats", "books", "houses"];
let noun3Array = ["balls", "games", "spatulas"];
let verbArray = ["bolt", "leap", "fall"];
let verb2Array = ["lay", "sing", "skate"];
let adjectiveArray = ["golden", "chosen", "eerie"];
let adjective2Array = ["cautious", "slim", "probable"];
let adjective3Array = ["wide", "ossified", "overjoyed"];

function madlib2()
{
    let storyContent = "All of the " + nounArray + " and " + noun2Array + " were gone when he awoke, finding that the " + noun3Array + " now continued uninterrupted in their place. He tried to " + verbArray + " for help, but was " + adjectiveArray + " to find that his mouth was " + adjective2Array + ", the lower half of his face now " + adjective3Array + ", continuous flesh. He tried to " + verb2Array + " his panic by closing his eyes and counting to ten. On the eleventh second of darkness, he realised his mistake."

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = storyContent;
}

let randomBtn = document.getElementById("button2");
randomBtn.addEventListener('click', madlib2);

function showhide()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("content");
    div.classList.toggle('hidden');
    var div = document.getElementById("end");
    div.classList.toggle('hidden');
    var div = document.getElementById("line");
    div.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

function randomWord()
{
    console.log(nounArray[(Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length))]);
}
randomWord()
```

I tried the things I mentioned above and they didn't work.

Comment: You `randomWord()` function should actually ***return*** its result. Then when you build your story you need to warp your arrays in your  `randomWord()` function.

Comment: `"All of the " + nounArray`: you're including the entire array there. Your way of getting a random word works if you do something with the random noun. RIght now, you generate a random noun, then give it to `console.log`, which just prints it to the console. If you want to use that random noun elsewhere (like in another string), you need to return it from your function: `function randomWord() { return nounArray[(Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length))]; }`. Then `const randomNoun = randomWord();  let storyContent = "All of the " + randomWord`

Comment: @Carcigenicate How can I make that work for multiple arrays, since I need different types of words (nouns, verbs, adjectives)? I'm combing all the nouns into one array, verbs into another, etc., but when I try to add another return line in that function, it fades out. EDIT: I just thought of a way: make two more functions (randomVerb, randomAdjective) and just do the same thing. Not the most efficient, but it should work.

Comment: Give the function a parameter and pass the array you want to use into the function as an argument: `function randomWord(arr) {`, then use `arr` internally instead of `nounArray`.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was solved by having generic programming techniques helpfully explained to the user.